# 2.81 "Alpha" drop down menu in Scene>Film tab missing?

Tags: transparency

[image]I changed from cycles to evee and back and there is no setting to change Alhpa from sky to transparent, I'm trying to make the background transparent in cycles and nothing is working please help, RGBA is ticked, Scene>File>Transparent is ticked yet still nothing.

Comment: the transparent tick was marked but it still shows the background

Comment: Show an image of what you see as the background (e.g an example viepowrt render screenshot). Maybe there is an object which obscures the transparent background

Answer (score 1):

I played around with some of the settings i used, it looks like the Volume scatter in the shading tab was the problem i removed it and it works now

Comment: i can mark as answered in 2 days